# Access items of fixed size list using hashing

Tags: java, hash

I have a list of x items and and I need to access them using hash (so objects with the same hash will get the same item). Now obviously this is easy to implement (use an `ArrayList` and `get(int index)` where the index is `abs(hashCode) % list.size()`) but I wasn't able to understand what native data structure provides this kind of utility.

If I'm using `Map<Integer, T>` then not all keys will have values.
Basically I need a fixed size hashmap which is full

Comment: What about a `HashSet`?

Comment: @MCEmperor set doesn't provide `get()`

Comment: Well, I'm not entirely sure what actual problem you are trying to solve here. Could you provide more details?

Comment: You can't use a `List` in the way you suggested either. There is no guarantee that `x` arbitrary items will hash in a 1-to-1 relationship with the natural numbers `0, ..., x - 1`.

Comment: @polo-language at insertion I'm not hashing, I'm inserting them sequentially.

Comment: How are you not inserting them by hash but "need to access them using hash"? Anyway, I'm referring to your proposal that "the index is `abs(hashCode) % list.size())`", that won't insert them sequentially (i.e. first at index 0, then at 1, 2, etc.) nor will it be guaranteed to fill up the list without overwriting earlier writes, for the reason I gave before.

Comment: @polo-language I have a predefined list of locks (`Object`) and I need items `T` that have the same hash code to acquire the same lock. So there is no "Insertion".
Anyway, I just used: `Map<T, Object> locks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); Object lock = locks.computeIfAbsent(k, k -> new Object());

Thanks for the help